# How to refer a public variable and refer it to different scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code like this:

```
public bool foodEaten=true;
```

I'm able to view it in the Unity Editor having a checkbox with a check.
If I refer the same variable on a different scene, it asks me to change it to static. If I do that, I'm not able to view it in the Unity Editor. How will I do both in which I can still see the same variable in Unity Editor, but I'm able to refer it on a different scene. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one simpel solution, you can make a local non-static variable "foodEaten_nonstatic" and give it the same value as the static one.

`public void Update(){
foodEaten_nonstatic = foodEaten;
}`

But you can't change the value of it in the inspector!